# Bootstrap 3 carousel navigator active class not updating

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

The navigator navigates slides without problems, except the active class stays on the first navigator.

Here is my code:

```html
<div id="homepanel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ol class="home-tabs">
        <li>Featured Products</li>
        <li data-target="#homepanel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">Slide 1</a></li>
        <li data-target="#homepanel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Slide 2</a></li>

      </ol>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <img alt="Cardboard Boxes" src="/slide1.png" class="no-border-radius">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="content">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, sint.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <img alt="Multi-wall Sacks" src="/slide2.jpg" class="no-border-radius">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="content">
                <p>Molestiae incidunt excepturi dolorum autem eum illum ipsa facilis sed.</p>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

li.active does not change at all. Is anything missing in my code? Any ideas?

I have enclosed a jsfiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/wpyz4c22/

Comment: Try to demonstrate this issue with a `Bootply` or `jsFiddle`: code snippets don't handle this very well it would seem.

Comment: @TimLewis Hi, I have added a jsfiddle link. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carousel need an extra-class on the indicators to change the li active-state. You where lacking that class : `.carousel-indicators`

Find the JSFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/Bladepianist/tzrnjdkk/

```
<div id="homepanel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ol class="home-tabs carousel-indicators">

        <li data-target="#homepanel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">Slide 1</a></li>
        <li data-target="#homepanel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Slide 2</a></li>

      </ol>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <img alt="Cardboard Boxes" src="http://placehold.it/310x200" class="no-border-radius">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <img alt="Multi-wall Sacks" src="http://placehold.it/310x200" class="no-border-radius">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your reply. The first Featured Products list item is just a label. it is not a navigator. The active class is still not updating in the JSFiddle.

Comment: Hey ! I edited the answer. Hope it's more helpful ;).

Comment: That's why. Thanks a lot.